# apt-get broken after update to Ubuntu 18

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

After an Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 upgrade virtually all calls to `apt-get install` result in errors of this sort ...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 texstudio : Depends: libpoppler-qt5-1 (>= 0.24.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Note that I see something similar on every package I try to install.

I have tried the various `sudo apt-get -f install`, `sudo apt-get clean`, etc. to no avail.  Also I removed all other repositories, and only have official ones left.

So, the big question is have I nuked my system?

Comment: Do you have 'universe' enabled?  (it's an official repository), and to have no issues you need to not only remove unofficial sources for upgrade; but also remove unofficial packages prior to upgrade; then re-add back if needed post-upgrade. You also need to read and deal with the messages for your `sudo apt-get -f install` command if you get any warnings or errors.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libpoppler-qt5&searchon=names   was used in prior comment

Comment: in my `sources.list` I have `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: You need to run `sudo apt update` first. Sometimes `sudo apt install -f` will produce different error messages than `apt-get` IIRC.

Comment: @karel I dont have held packages ...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I did that of course.  didn't make one difference

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies: texstudio : Depends: libpoppler-qt5-1 (>= 0.24.5) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: `sudo apt install libpoppler-qt5-1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: If you haven't solved this yet, please [edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`